# Scott Pilgrim's Ramona Analysis

Tags: guitar, theory, chord-progressions

Can anyone well versed in music theory help me comprehend what is going on in Scott Pilgrim's Ramona?

From what I can tell, there are 3 sets of 3 chords, each seem to be going to a specific place. But I cannot pin the progression or how the key(s) are moving.

Here is what I can grasp from the chords:

G - Bm7 - E

Am - C/G - D#/A# (?!)

A# - Dm7 - G

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwYjaAzejuk) to the song in the movie for those who aren't familiar.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I'd suspect those D#/A# and A# chords should really be Eb/Bb and Bb chords, respectively. They fit so much better with the Dm7 chord.

Answer (score 2):

As Dekkadeci says in a comment, I think the D♯ and A♯ chords are best understood as E♭ and B♭ chords, respectively. I also hear some different inversions in there, giving us:

G Bm7/F♯ E

Am C E♭

B♭ Dm7 G

By its nature the song is incomplete (that's the joke in the movie), so it's hard to know exactly where it "should" go, but I hear this as something like:

- We begin in G. We then have a standard descending bassline that ultimately creates a nice ii–V–i (Bm–E–Am) that moves to Am.
- At this point, the chords progress up by consecutive minor thirds. This doesn't sound "odd" until the E♭, since the C chord is diatonic both in the original G and the temporary Am.
- This E♭ then serves to briefly make the subsequent B♭ as tonic; this is just a nice IV–I progression in B♭.
- At this point, I hear the Dm7 moving to G as the start of another ii–V–I progression similar to how the music moved to Am in the first phrase. In this case, it moves to C, and I hear the final G chord as a very clear V. But again, it's tough to know for sure if this is how it's functioning, since the music doesn't continue. But my ears hear a distinct move to B♮ in this final G chord, and that alteration from the recently heard B♭ makes B♮ sound like the leading tone of C.